# How can I program an esp 32 stuck in deep sleep

Tags: esp32

I have an esp32 that I've uploaded a loop of a 2 second LED flash on, followed by a 5 second deep sleep.

When I try to reprogram the unit it becomes undiscoverable (no board connected to port) while in deep sleep.

Is there a way to reset the board so I can get rid of the deep sleep mode?

Or am I stuck with a board I cant re-program?

Comment: Deep sleep doesn't do that, you've got some other problem.

Comment: Any idea why it might happen? I've uploaded to the board hundreds of times,  but the first time I upload a deepsleep sketch it does it. Or how I can do a master reset?

Comment: put it into flashing mode. then it stays in bootloader. it is impossible to brick the esp32 by software.

Comment: How do you program the board? USB? ESP-PROG? Do you have one or two buttons on the board (reset and boot)

Comment: There are a lot of different ESP32 boards out there; it could be how you're using the board, it could be your USB cable, it could be your host computer. Not enough information to offer an opinion. The one thing it's definitely not is deep sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely not stuck. See there are 2 modes an ESP32 can be in.

1. Mode 1 : Programming Running Mode
2. Mode 2 : Boot Mode
   Boot Mode is the mode we put the ESP32 in before we upload a new code. This should be in normal case be independent modes, meaning if in boot mode, the deep sleep code shouldn't work.

I suspect when you try to upload new code, its somehow in program running mode.

Why don't you try this:

1. Disconnect your ESP32
2. Keep Pressing the Boot Button
3. Then connect the ESP32 to USB cable
4. This way as soon as power flows to the ESP32 it doesn't get to program running mode, and directly will go to Boot Mode.
5. Now upload the code.

This should work.

If still the issue persists, maybe you need to flash the ESP32 bootloader firmware manually. Please try the above and update your progress.

I hope this answer was helpful.

Thank You.
Naveen PS

Comment: it is not possible to "to flash the ESP32 bootloader firmware". why do you assume OP has a dev board with a boot button, but without a reset button?

Comment: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-feather-32u4-radio-with-lora-radio-module.pdf 

It only has a reset button. 
I double tapped the reset button to put it into flash mode. The flash mode was only active for 10 seconds but the compile took 30 seconds. So I had to do a little bit of timing and start the flash right before the end of the compiling. It worked though. I was able to load an easy "blinking led" sketch.

Comment: Hi LAAD, I am happy that you were able to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: I could update firmware after stuck in deep sleep mode. 

1. connect FTDI's USB-to-UART module's RX/TX pin with ESP32's TX/RX pin then press en button and reset button for manual download mode. 
2. then find out comport of FTDI. Update blink example through comport of FTDI.